# HasFlag() always returns true in Enum foreach statement

Tags: c#, foreach, enums, flags

Thanks for taking the time to try help me.

I've ran into a rather weird issue. I'm trying to loop through all the Enum values to check if my object contains the Enum flag. But for some reason, that I do not quite understand, in the foreach it says it always has the flag. But in the separate if statements it does work exactly how I wanted. But I do not want to repeat code 6 times, so I would like to have the foreach statement working.

Does anybody know what is happening? Maybe some background information why it's happening?

Sorry for my English, it's not my native language.

Thanks in advance!

Code is changed from the original, but it's essentially the same.

Code below.

```
[Flags]
public enum SampleEnum
{
    Enum1 = 0,
    Enum2 = 1,
    Enum3 = 2,
    Enum4 = 4,
    Enum5 = 8,
    Enum6 = 16,
};

SampleEnum sample = SampleEnum.Enum1 | SampleEnum.Enum2;



    // This doesn't work
    foreach (SampleEnum enum in Enum.GetValues(typeof(SampleEnum)))
    {
      // This is statement says it allways has the flags. Even tho it doesn't have the flag.
        if(sample.HasFlag(enum))
        {
            // This is always true.
        }
    }

    // This works
    if (sample.HasFlag(SampleEnum.Enum2))
    {
        // true
    }

    // This works
    if (sample.HasFlag(SampleEnum.Enum3))
    {
        // false
    }


    // This works
    if (sample.HasFlag(SampleEnum.Enum4))
    {
        // false
    }
}
```

Comment: If you put `Enum.GetValues(typeof(MainSettings.ConnectedPrinters)).Cast<MainSettings.ConnectedPrinters>()` does it work then? `GetValues` returntype is non generic `Array`.

Comment: What is the value of printGroup, at the loop where `.HasFlag` always evaluates to true?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I seem to recall that having an element with value 0 means that everything contains that when using the HasFlag with [Flags] directive.  Try this code:

```
Enum.GetValues(typeof(MainSettings.ConnectedPrinters)).Cast<MainSettings.ConnectedPrinters>().Where(v => (int)v > 0).ToList())
```

This will iterate the list without the 0 valued flag.

Comment: Thank you! This was indeed the case. Tho I cannot mark your answer as correct since I do not have 15 points. :(

Comment: @AlexanderDerck Ah I see, apperent if you click upvote first, it doesn't register the accept button because of that message.

Answer (score 2):

You should never create Flags enum with a 0 value as it'll do bitwise comparison of the element with 0.

AnyEnumItem & 0 always equals 0.

Edit : Except for an "All item"

Comment: "You should never" are strong words. You might want to have a flag that represents it, f. e., on permissions – 0 could indicate all.

Comment: Thanks, I updated my answer and added the "All" enum member for the 0 value.

Answer (score 1):

From [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.enum.hasflag(v=vs.110).aspx) about `HasFlag`:

> If the underlying value of *flag* is zero, the method returns **true**.

You should check for zero before using `HasFlag`.